# Dont understand the coding behind Assert.Areequal

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me with this?

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void MakeDateConstructsADateTimeFromYearMonthAndDay()
    {
        Arrange
        var controller = new DateController();
        var expected = new DateTime(2014, 6, 30);

        Act
        var result = controller.MakeDate(2014, 6, 30);

        Assert
        Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MakeDateReturnsDefaultDateTimeIfInputDataInvalid()
    {
        /* HINT You need to use a try ... catch block in the MakeDate()
         * method to trap the exception thrown by the DateTime constructor.
         * See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110)/ 
         * for information on the exceptions thrown by the DateTime 
         * constructor.  
         * See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.110).aspx 
         * for information on exception handling in C#.  
         * */
        //Arrange
        var controller = new DateController();//error
        var expected = new DateTime();//error

        //Act
        //June has only 30 days so this will cause an exception
        var result = controller.MakeDate(2014, 6, 31);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
    }
```

Keep getting error stating Error Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
//getting errors under 'void, datacontroller and datetime

Comment: It asserts that the expected value is equal to the actual value.  What else would it do?

Comment: Please give some more details about what excatly You don't unerstand about it. It just matches the value (or reference) of the `result` parameter with the one specified in `expected` parameter.

Comment: I dont understand this line of code Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
```

That line of code *Asserts* that its two arguments *Are Equal*.  This is a generic method, so the `<DatTime>` bit is what tells the method what the type of the two arguments are.  Something like:

```
bool SomeGenericCompareMethod<T>( T arg1, T arg2 )
{
    // use reference equality by default, 
    // implementation may override .Equals()
    return arg1.Equals( arg2 );
}
```

---

EDIT:

Per your completely unformatted and garbled code in the comments, what is this exactly?

```
Arrange var controller = new DateController();//Getting Error
```

That makes no sense.  You seem to have two type declarators, `Arrange` and `var`.  Pick one.  I would go with this because it's not clear that `Arrange` is a base class/interface that `DateController` derived from:

```
var controller = new DateController();//Getting Error
```

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void MakeDateConstructsADateTimeFromYearMonthAndDay()
        {
            Arrange
            var controller = new DateController();//Getting Error
            var expected = new DateTime(2014, 6, 30);//Getting Error

            Act
            var result = controller.MakeDate(2014, 6, 30);

            Assert
            Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
        }// need help i keep getting errors stating expected class,delegate,enum, interface or struct, got errors under void, errors under var controller and var expected

Comment: @AbdullahAl-Mansur: Then that's the question you should have asked, not something completely unrelated. Please post your code in the original post and format it.

Answer (score 0):

Assertions can be used as runtime cheks in the application (i.e. the method You've mentioned compares two parameters and verifies if they're equal using equality operator).

If an assertion evaluates to `true`, it just let the code to continue, but if it evaluates to `false`, `AssertFailedException` is thrown.

For some information on msdn take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

Comment: Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct neeed help with this please